# Why does an @objc enum have a different description than a pure Swift enum?

Tags: swift, enums

Consider two Swift enums:

```
enum Foo: Int {
    case bar
}

@objc enum Baz: Int {
    case qux
}
```

If I were to `print` each `case` of these enums, I would expect the same result.  Instead, I see something unexpected:

```
print(Foo.bar) // "bar\n"
print(Baz.qux) // "Baz\n"
```

Why does printing a case of an `@objc` enum print the enum name, while printing the `case` of a pure Swift enum print the actual `case` name?  Does adding `@objc` change the debug description of the enum?

Comment: Swift enums carry more metadata (the case labels) than ObjC ones. ObjC enums are just a series of int, with no real knowledge of the case labels they represent. You can get around it by switching on the enum, and returning different strings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14651888/3141234

Comment: @Alexander Thank you so much! This finally makes some sort of sense to me. I thought I was  going crazy because all the posts I've seen suggested that printing an enum in Swift would show the case, even though I was clearly looking at an example of that not being the case (CBCentralManagerState). Thank you!

Comment: It would be far more useful if the debugger printed the enum case's `rawValue` rather than the name of the enum...

Answer (score 2):

That is because `@objc` enums are "C-compatible enums", which intentionally do not emit any reflection information about their cases.

Since Swift is open source, we can nose around to see this for ourselves:

- [`@objc` enums are treated as C-compatible enums](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2017-04-24-a/lib/IRGen/GenEnum.cpp#L5069-L5078)
- [C-compatible enums intentionally don't emit case info for reflection](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2017-04-24-a/lib/IRGen/GenEnum.cpp#L1089-L1095)
- [Other enums do emit case info](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2017-04-24-a/lib/IRGen/GenEnum.cpp#L153-L167)

That's one version of "why", the implementation-focused. Now, let's step back one level and ask, **why was it implemented this way?** The comment by the `emitCaseNames` function for the C-compatible enums explains this: C-compatible enums don't guarantee a mapping from the enum raw value back to the tag, because, unlike the Swift-native enums, they can have multiple cases that all have the same raw value.

Now, if you try to declare an enum in Swift that duplicates raw values, you'll get your hand slapped and a compiler error. But you should be able to create such an enum by declaring the enum in Obj/C and then importing it into Swift over the bridge.