# What's the easiest way to print the value of a variable of type UIInterfaceOrientation?

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, xcode-debugger

As I debug my app, I want to print out the value of a local variable `orien` of type `UIInterfaceOrientation`.

I tried `print("\(orien")` but it printed:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation
```

... which is obviously useless.

I then tried `dump(orien)`, which produced another useless output:

```
- __C.UIInterfaceOrientation
```

In Xcode, I set a breakpoint and right-clicked the variable and chose `Print Description of`, which produced:

```
Printing description of orien:
(UIInterfaceOrientation) orien = <variable not available>
```

I ended up writing:

```
extension UIInterfaceOrientation {
  func dump() {
    switch self {
    case .portrait: print("Interface orientation is Portrait")
    case .portraitUpsideDown: print("Interface orientation is Portrait upside down")
    case .landscapeLeft: print("Interface orientation is Landscape left")
    case .landscapeRight: print("Interface orientation is Landscape right")
    case .unknown: print("Interface orientation is unknown")
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better solution?

BTW, this problem also occurred with a CGFloat — XCode's debugger printed it out as `<variable not available>`.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588375/how-to-display-optionset-values-in-human-readable-form

Comment: @matt, No, not a dupe, because that question is about an OptionSet, and UIInterfaceOrientation is not an OptionSet.

Comment: I appreciate that, and that's why I didn't dupehammer it closed. But the point is the same: we don't get the string names of the cases in the console, and it's maddening. At present your own solution is to log the numeric value and figure out what it means. File an enhancement request with Apple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just print the rawValue of the enum case? Apparently, this isn't possible because it returns a Int because `UIInterfaceOrientation` is a enum of Int.

EDIT: The following code could help because it creates a description, using a variable.

```
extension UIInterfaceOrientation {
public var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .landscapeLeft: return "landscapeLeft"
    case .landscapeRight: return "landscapeRight"
    case .portrait: return "portrait"
    case .portraitUpsideDown: return "portraitUpsideDown"
    case .unknown: return "unknown"
    }
}
}
```

After this addition, you can use `description` in the following way:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.description

landscapeLeft
```

Comment: I get a number like 1. Is there a way to print a readable string representation? And, for other data types, like UIInterfaceOrientationMask, I get a value like 30, and the documentation doesn't even say what that corresponds to, so the number 30 is useless.

Comment: I see that UIInterfaceOrientation is an enum type of Int. So the rawValue gives back a Int value between 0 - 4 and no String. To bad :).

You can create a extensions that maps the case to the String description (which you have done).

Comment: Any idea why the Xcode debugger is able to print out the value?

Comment: What do you mean with why? What value is print out?

Comment: As the question says: <variable not available>

Comment: Ah, the debugger thinks there is a string description available. I would file a bug at Apple to solve this.